# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost

Tags: android, node.js, linux, webpack-dev-server

What could cause the error seen in the screenshot below?

[image]

Comment: What is in `/etc/hosts`? It seems like you may be missing a `127.0.0.1 localhost` entry in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

problem solved with add 127.0.0.1 localhost in /etc/hosts

thanks